# Bypass Confirm Action Dialog Box

Tags: powershell

I have a simple code where I'm deleting certain users from Distribution Groups. However, whenever it attempts to delete a user, a dialog box appears asking me if I really want to delete the user. It does this for every user I try to delete. Is there a way to make it so that box doesn't appear, and says yes automatically?

Here's my code:

```
#Accept input parameters
Param(
      [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      [string] $DistributionGroup   
     )

$DL = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroup | select windowsliveid, name | where windowsliveid -like '*c-*'
$DL

$DL | % {
    Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroup -Member $_.name
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove users from distribution groups without additional confirmation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534054/remove-users-from-distribution-groups-without-additional-confirmation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set $confirm to false explicitly, it shouldn't prompt you to confirm.

```
Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroup -Member $_.name -Confirm:$False
```

Alternatively, you can try -force parameter as well.

```
Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroup -Member $_.name -Force
```

PS: Test above changes before trying out in production environment.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/03afb508-12f2-4173-a94d-273dc7b848b4/how-to-stop-getting-prompted-to-confirm?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 3):

Normally this should work:

```
Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DistributionGroup -Member $_.name -Confirm:$False
```

As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534054/remove-users-from-distribution-groups-without-additional-confirmation).

Comment: I tried adding -Confirm:$true and it still displays the dialog box.

Comment: You should try False instead of True