# How to surpass the Windows dialog box using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**The below code is able to delete the Folder From a Zip File.**

```
Sub del_fol_from_Zip()

CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace("C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Test\test\first.zip\first\second").Self.Verbs.Item(4).DoIt


End Sub
```

- But the problem is the Windows Confirmation of Deletion, which appears right after the line is Executed.

[image]

[Link with the Sample Zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11Mjs3uCjvAzrbiBHNaBSAm5pI7BQFSJA)

I have tried to use `Application.DisplayAlerts` but that only covers the Alert created by Excel Application. All the google results are related to Excel Alerts and no information on the Windows Alerts.

I found this link, but it is for Powershell. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146436/bypass-confirm-action-dialog-box) Talks about passing `$confirm` or `Force` to surpass the Warning.

[Main Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490063/deleting-a-folder-from-a-zip-file)

Can we pass any argument in the above line or some other way to surpass the error using `Shell` ?

Comment: Not sure but can use APIs to click "Yes" on that alert window :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout ... Can you point to a link or any other source for more information ? Google doesn't give any results beyond the Deletion of Sheets and Cells. :(

Comment: I can wrtie the code for you but it is slightly complex. It would be much easier to unzip and delte the folder and rezip :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout .. Haha okay .... I will do that only then. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout ... I think I should play a little and make it work myself. Will get to learn about it as well. Thank you so much for pointing in that direction.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295677/how-can-i-simulate-a-button-click-given-the-handle-to-the-buttons-window) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

## Recycle Bin's properties dialog

One way to avoid the confirmation dialog would be to preemptively disable the `Display delete confirmation dialog` property inside the Recycle Bin's properties dialog (right click on the Recycle Bin > Properties):

[image]

The issue here is that you probably don't want you or the people running your macro to keep this setting disabled all the time since it's useful to prevent unintentional deletion. So, we want this setting to be disabled only when the macro runs.

To make this change temporary, you could prompt the user at the beginning and at the end of your macro to disable and then re-enable that setting. For instance, this line of code would prompt the user with the Recycle Bin's properties dialog.

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(ssfBITBUCKET).Self.Verbs.Item(#).DoIt
```

Where `#` is the position (starting at 0) of the `Properties` item in the context menu for the Recycle Bin. If in doubt, assign `CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(ssfBITBUCKET).Self.Verbs` to a variable and have a look at the Locals Window in debug mode.

If you were to make multiple deletion in your macro, this would at least reduce the number of dialog windows that appears, but assuming your goal is for this process to be fully automated, it still ain't what we want.

## Uncheck the checkbox in the dialog automatically?

You could probably use the Window's API function SendMessage to uncheck the checkbox and then [press the OK button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295677/how-can-i-simulate-a-button-click-given-the-handle-to-the-buttons-window), but at this point, you might as well just use that technique to press the YES button inside the `delete confirmation dialog` in the first place (as mentioned by Siddharth Rout).

## Change the corresponding Registry key

Yes, there is [a Registry key for this setting](https://www.isumsoft.com/it/enable-delete-confirmation-dialog-box-in-windows-10-8/), so you could also consider [making a change into the Registry with VBA](https://vba-corner.livejournal.com/3054.html) in order to change this setting automatically.

Note that I haven't tested this and making changes to the registry is subject to the usual precautionary warning. However, this option seems promising and if I have the time to test it, I'll update this answer with my findings. I'm assuming that you might need to do something to [make your Registry change take effect immediately without restart](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-make-registry-changes-take-effect-immediately-without-restart), but hopefully this is enough information to put you on the right track.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but disabling the dialog box from the Properties Section **wont make the dialog disappear when deleting from a Zip File**. ~~Also I have to implement this in a bigger code and it would be used by like 50 users who don't have Admin Access on their systems, so I can't edit the registry or change settings. Though this is very useful information :)

Comment: @Mikku  Honestly, I just thought this was a very interesting question and wanted to make and share my own research. I agree that the information there is useful, but not necessarily for this exact question (except maybe the link I already put in the comments).

Comment: Yeah ... Indeed it is useful information and can be used in future by people looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `RmDir`, it won't cause window alert to pop up:

```
Sub DeleteTest()
    RmDir "path to the catalog"
End Sub
```

Comment: Gives an Error `Path Not Found` .. The file exists in a Zip Folder